# Buscar dados de uma determinada coluna e exibi-los em um Spinner

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Estou buscando os registros do banco de dados Sqlite e exibindo em um Spinner , porém o Spinner esta exibindo todos registros da tabela , e eu preciso exibir apenas os registros de uma determinada coluna .

Tentei alterar a query :

De :

```
 String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LABELS;
```

para :

```
 String selectQuery = "SELECT modelo FROM " + TABLE_LABELS;
```

Porém ocorreu um erro no cursor.

```
Erro : Failed to read row 0, column 1 from a CursorWindow which has 12 rows, 1 columns.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

Segue abaixo código :

```
package com.example.d2;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Medidores";

    private static final String TABLE_LABELS = "labels";

    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_MODELO = "modelo";    

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LABELS + "("+ KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_MODELO + " TEXT)"; // removi o modelo e seu tipo
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LABELS);

        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void insertLabel(String nome,String modelo) { // alterei de void para long
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME , nome);
        values.put(KEY_MODELO, modelo);

        db.insert(TABLE_LABELS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    public List<String> getAllLabels() {
        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LABELS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                labels.add(cursor.getString(1));

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // closing connection
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // returning lables
        return labels;
    }

    public List<String> BuscaModelos() {
        List<String> modelos = new ArrayList<String>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LABELS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                modelos.add(cursor.getString(1));

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return modelos;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `Cursor` no Android inicia com índice 0.

Troque o `modelos.add(cursor.getString(1));` por `modelos.add(cursor.getString(0));`.

Você pode consultar o índice de uma coluna baseada em seu nome, usando o `getColumnIndex(String name)` para não haver erro.

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int indiceDaColuna = cursor.getColumnIndex("NOME_DA_COLUNA");

    do {
        modelos.add(cursor.getString(indiceDaColuna));
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Cuidado, porque o `getColumnIndex` por retornar `-1` se não existe a coluna.

Comment: Obrigado , @Walkim ,
Deu certo , agora posso "caminhar" com meu TCC
Vlw